# Is there a way to use PyGithub on AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Im a big fan of  PyGithub. I want use this library on AWS Lambda. But unfortunately,Im not able compile and use the source files of  PyGithub.

I tried to download it from pypi, then compressed it as zip --> uploaded.

```
## app.py file
from github import Github

# using username and password
g = Github("username", "password")

def handler(event, context):
    for repo in g.get_user().get_repos():
        print(repo.name)
        repo.edit(has_wiki=False)
```

But its throwing an error.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'jwt'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"
}
```

Is there any way to use this library on Lambda?

Comment: Did you follow [AWS Lambda deployment package in Python](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. One way would be through [lambda layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html).

To **verify** this possibility, I just created a custom layer with `pygithub` and can confirm that it **works**.

The technique used includes **docker tool** described in the recent **AWS blog**:

- [How do I create a Lambda layer using a simulated Lambda environment with Docker?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-layer-simulated-docker/)

I created the layer  as follows:

1. Create empty folder, e.g. `mylayer`.
2. Go to the folder and create `requirements.txt` file with the content of

```
PyGithub
```

3. Run the following docker command (for lambda with python 3.8):

```
docker run -v "$PWD":/var/task "lambci/lambda:build-python3.8" /bin/sh -c "pip install -r requirements.txt -t python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/; exit"
```

4. Create layer as zip:

```
zip -r mypygithublayer.zip python > /dev/null
```

5. Create lambda layer based on `mypygithublayer.zip` in the AWS Console. Don't forget to specify `Compatible runtimes` to `python3.8`.
6. Test the layer in lambda using the following lambda function:

```
import json

from github import Github

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    print(dir(Github))
```

The function executes correctly:

```
['FIX_REPO_GET_GIT_REF', '_Github__get_FIX_REPO_GET_GIT_REF', '_Github__get_per_page', '_Github__set_FIX_REPO_GET_GIT_REF', '_Github__set_per_page', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'create_from_raw_data', 'dump', 'get_emojis', 'get_events', 'get_gist', 'get_gists', 'get_gitignore_template', 'get_gitignore_templates', 'get_hook', 'get_hooks', 'get_installation', 'get_license', 'get_licenses', 'get_oauth_application', 'get_organization', 'get_organizations', 'get_project', 'get_project_column', 'get_rate_limit', 'get_repo', 'get_repos', 'get_user', 'get_users', 'load', 'oauth_scopes', 'per_page', 'rate_limiting', 'rate_limiting_resettime', 'render_markdown', 'search_code', 'search_commits', 'search_issues', 'search_repositories', 'search_topics', 'search_users']
```

Comment: CLI command to deploy layer: 

`aws lambda publish-layer-version --layer-name PyGithub --zip-file pygithub-layer.zip --compatible-runtimes "python3.8" --description "AWS Lambda Layer for PyGithub built on Linux"`